# Action of grupoids on sets

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

Let E : C → C′ be an equivalence of categories. Show that the induced functor H:Fun(C′,D)→Fun(C,D),
F→F◦E
is an equivalence for any category D.
I am trying to solve this exercise from  a topology course using the characterisation of equivalences, so proving that H is essentially surjective and fully faithful, but I am having some problem as I lack some knowledge of categories. Any help is welcome :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Just write down an inverse functor.